# preview.sty and font transparency in LuaLaTeX

Tags: transparency, preview, luaotfload

Using the preview package removes font transparency in LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\usepackage[active]{preview}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\font\x="texgyrebonum-bold.otf:color=FF000077" at 24pt\x
ABCDEF\llap{ZYXWUV}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

(Remove the `active` option to preview to see what it's supposed to look like.)

Before I dive into the details myself to investigate here, any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: "the version about to be submitted to CTAN"... of which package? `preview`?

Comment: @giordano Sorry for the confusion — I meant `fontspec`.

Comment: I've minimised the example to remove fontspec use.

Comment: Your comment implies you are trying to use both luaotfload and fontspec even though your MWE does not explicitly use fontspec. Does preview depend on the latter? luaotfload has some conflicts with fontspec. That there is a conflict is even documented. :)

Comment: The example can be further minimized: you just need to load `preview` and use the environment; one letter is sufficient.

Comment: @BillMeahan If you read the history, you'll see Will first had `fontspec` in the demo and some code that the comment applied about, then cut it down to just `luaoftload` to reduced toward a minimal example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `luaotfload`'s handling of the pdf page resources.

The example can be further reduced (and plainified) by removing the `preview` package -- a simple `\vbox` is enough:

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\font\x="texgyrebonum-bold.otf:color=FF000077" at 24pt\x
AAA \newbox\y\setbox\y\vbox{AAA}\unvbox\y
\bye
```

The effect is that the setting of the `pdfpageresources` (which must contain the transparency spec) does not propagate out of the vbox. (What I do not quite understand, though, is why there is no transparency even though the transparent font is also used outside of the vbox.)

The `pdfpageresoures` are set in `luaotfload-colors.lua`, in the function `color_handler`, near the end of the file. Changing the line

```
    tex.pdfpageresources=tpr
```

to

```
    tex.set('global','pdfpageresources',tpr)
```

seems to resolve the issue.